# Copy log files from Docker container to host after CMD is run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Currently I have a Dockerfile that will build an image with an ENTRYPOINT that allows me to run a command in a CentOS based container using the `docker run` command. After this command is run, the Docker container is stopped and removed.

However, the command that is run will generate some log files inside the Docker container and these will immediately be lost once the container exits. What is the best practice for preserving these files (preferably so they can be stored on my host machine)?

Comment: you should read https://www.loggly.com/docs/docker-syslog/ , https://www.loggly.com/blog/top-5-docker-logging-methods-to-fit-your-container-deployment-strategy/ and https://gist.github.com/afolarin/a2ac14231d9079920864

Comment: You can mount the place where your logfiles are stored to your host.

Comment: I have read a bit about loggly and am considering using it. It would be very simple if I could do this @lorenzvth7 but the logfiles are not generated until after the docker container is started (if I mount the directory to my host upon starting the container my log directory will be empty I believe)

Comment: @kshah I don't really know. It's easy to setup so I would recommend to give it a try. E.G. when you start a container with an empty mount and you perform a docker exec to go inside the container and create a test.txt in the right folder + exit and delete your container. Than the test.txt will be on the folder on your host I think.

Comment: @lorenzvth7 I have tried it and it does not seem to work--the logs directory I populate with my ENTRYPOINT command is empty. However, I will continue to look into this

Answer (score 1):

This may be a solution:
Create a named docker volume:

```
docker volume create --name centos-volume
```

So the path to his volume on your host is `/var/lib/docker/volumes/centos-volume/_data`

Than I created something which is hopefully comparable with your app.
My dockerfile (copies a script which will create a log in my container. I start the script when I start the container with docker run (like you did)):

```
FROM centos:7
RUN mkdir /script
COPY create-log.sh /script/
RUN chmod +x /script/create-log.sh
```

Content of the script: (it creates a logfile in `/var/log/anaconda`)

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /var/log/anaconda/my-log.log
echo "hello world" >> /var/log/anaconda/my-log.log
```

I start my container with:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v centos-volume:/var/log/anaconda/ my-centos ./script/create-log.sh
```

So this commands execute the script in my container and mounts the content of my `/var/log/anaconda` folder of my container to my volume on my host.

Than I check:

```
cat /var/lib/docker/volumes/centos-volume/_data/my-log.log
hello world
```

After rerunning the container the second log appears:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v centos-volume:/var/log/anaconda/ my-centos ./script/create-log.sh

$ sudo su
[root@localhost centos]# cat /var/lib/docker/volumes/centos-volume/_data/my-log.log
hello world
hello world
```